# Is it possible to dual-boot SteamOS with Asahi Linux’s UEFI environment on an M1 Mac?

Tags: mac, dual-boot, software

I was thinking about how [Asahi Linux](https://asahilinux.org) is based off of Arch, and how [SteamOS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SteamOS) is also based off of Arch (at least the Steam Deck version), and thought maybe I could install the Asahi Linux UEFI environment then boot off of a [Steam Deck recovery image](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/1B71-EDF2-EB6D-2BB3). Before I try it, has anyone else tried it already? Would it work theoretically?

Comment: "Do or do not, there is no try." I assume that Steam Deck lacks all the adaptions and device drivers Asahi had to add to Arch.

Comment: Very likely so but Asahi should add those drivers when it’s installed. Not sure if it would be enough. And btw, I kind of just want it to be bootable, it’s alright if it doesn’t entirely work as intended

Comment: Alright, I’m trying it. I’ve got Asahi installed, now I just need a USB stick to put the SteamOS installer onto. I probably have one at home, won’t be there until like 6 hours from now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, currently, it is not possible to boot SteamOS on an M1 Mac.**

I neglected to read that Steam Deck is actually x86 and not ARM like I assumed. Furthermore, in Asahi’s alpha release blog post, the developers stated that vanilla ARM64 images aren’t quite enough, and more work is needed for compatibility.

It is somewhat possible that SteamOS may be bootable eventually, but that would likely require an ARM processor being on a future Valve device running SteamOS, so probably not anytime soon.